# support multiple database servers with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, entity-framework, edmx

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 application running with SqlServer. I need to support multiple databases (SqlServer, Mysql and Oracle). The schema is the same for all databases.
[image]

The edmx is configured to run with SqlServer, so I added two new ssdl files: one for MYSQL and one for Oracle.
With SQLSERVER I can run the application, but when I try to set the connection string and metadata at runtime to be configured with MYSQL it generates exception:
[image: location of exception]

How would I go about altering the ssdl to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it specifically for MySql but this is what I've done to achieve multiple database support for Sql Server and Oracle. I believe the same approach works for MySql also. I expect you know how to set up Oracle client configuration. Changing the active connection string in application configuration file is all I need to do to target a different db.

1) Generate edmx against Sql Server.

2) Generate .ssdl and .msl files for Oracle. The latter contains entity property mappings. Data types need to be changed in ssdl for Oracle. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityEDMmapping.htm#ODPNT8275) link for detailed information. Oracle ssdl file needs to have the correct provider configuration, in my case: `Provider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"`.

3) Create new connection string for Oracle db connection in your application configuration file. It is crucial that namespaces are typed correctly here. Below is a working example:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomDb.csdl|res://CustomDbProject/CustomDbNamespace.CustomDb.ssdl|res://CustomDbProject/CustomDbNamespace.CustomDb.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=MYDS;USER ID=****;Password=****;Max Pool Size=**;Connection Timeout=120&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

4) Create a default constructor for context:

```
public CustomDb()
    : base("name=MyConnectionString")
{
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```